# Why are there gaps between my DIV's?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

Why are there gaps in [this website I'm working on](http://www.sarahcage.co.uk/)? I've tried setting margins, padding etc. to 0px but nothing seems to affect it.

*Edit - apologies; I screwed up the link to the website. This is now fixed.*

[image: image highlighting gaps between divs]

Comment: Maybe it's in the image?

Comment: Please push some CODE

Comment: And tell us which browser(s) you see the problem with, that also helps pinpoint it.

Comment: I think it is the Comic Sans font that is causing your problem. :-)

Comment: I see it now! There is no DOCTYPE anywhere in your image.

Comment: Check the link in the post for the code.

Comment: Comic Sans wouldn't be my choice, but users are always right *sigh* ...and the image is tiled across the background. The div's are on top of it.

Comment: Apologies, looks like my initial attempt to link to the website failed. I've fixed the link now.

Comment: The user is always right, especially when you go home to her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have inserted some styles you have forgotten about. Judging from the pic I would assume your html would look something like this like this

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="something">
</div>
```

your nav links or list items look as if they have a margin of 5px, and your div looks like it has top and bottom margin of 20px. Try to add this to your elements your are trying to fix to troubleshoot.

```
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
border: 0 !important;
```

This should override any css styles preceding that may be conflicting. If it doesn't work then we need to see code to help troubleshoot further.

[UPDATE]
You should declare a DOCTYPE instead of simply putting html tags. center tags are deprecated.

To fix your spacing try this:

```
#nav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
    /* REMOVE
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom:6px;  
    */
}  
/***********************************
-- ADD
***********************************/
hr {
    margin: 0;
}
h2 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

You changed the padding and margin to 0 but added it again in your ul. The hr tag was causing some of your spacing, and the heading tag was causing the rest.

Comment: Check the link in the post to the website for the source. I could distil it down to a short example if that helps.. ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it's looking better. Fair point on the doctype and center tags. There's still some spaces in there though. Is that down to the cf class?

Comment: Read my answer below to understand better. But you can fix the current problems with `.PageText p { margin: 0; }` as a paragraph is a block element.

Comment: Thanks Derek / Jonfer; between you, you've nailed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Give border zero width

```
style="border:0px"
```

or give color to check if it is border

```
style="border-color:red"
```

Answer (score 1):

HR (the line) and H2 (the home title) are Block elements by default and they have a line break and margins. You should modify the margins to those elements or set the display to inline (display:inline).

Comment: I wish I could accept more than one answer; Derek started me off but you finished it.

Answer (score 0):

Also try:

```
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 0;
```